# Reactjs touchevents not working

Tags: reactjs, touch-event, react-router

I am trying to trigger a class on touch tap. With onClick it works fine on desktop, but with onTap / onTouchStart / onTouchEnd the event does not get fired. I run `React.initializeTouchEvents(true)` before I render the components. The clickhandler is on a `div` element and I have set `cursor: pointer`. I am using a lonovo yoga 2 pro and an iPad for testing. In addition I use the [react router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router).
Anyone has an idea why it is not working?

Init:

```
React.initializeTouchEvents(true)
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler data={dummyData} />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Component:

```
var Transaction = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return ({showDetails: false})
  },
  toggleDetails: function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({showDetails: !this.state.showDetails})
  },
  render: function(){
    var itemClasses = "pl-transaction-item pl-transaction-status-"+this.props.data.status
    return (
      <li className={this.state.showDetails ? itemClasses + " pl-active" : itemClasses} >
        // here is the touch event listener
        <div className="pl-transaction-item-header" onTap={this.toggleDetails} onTouchEnd={this.toggleDetails}>
          <img src={this.props.data.img} alt="" /><span>name: {this.props.data.name}</span><span>status: {this.props.data.status}</span><span>date: {this.props.data.date}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="pl-transaction-item-details">
          <img src={this.props.data.img} alt="" />
          <ul>
            <li>name: {this.props.data.name}</li>
            <li>status: {this.props.data.status}</li>
            <li>date: {this.props.data.date}</li>
            <li><button>OK</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html
React does not have an `onTap` event listener.

Thus for `onTap` you might want to try to bind the onTap event on componentDidMount lifecycle, as done in http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html